# Why isn't the string len() operator O(n) in Python?

Tags: python, time, string-length

I really want to know how len() works. Shouldn't the time complexity of it be *O(n)*?

Comment: You could look at the source. Note that a Python string is an object with a `__len__` method, it isn't like a C-style string.

Comment: Can you please share source code?

Comment: The complexity of `len` depends the complexity of `__len__` defined by its argument's type. For lists, it's O(1) because a `list` stores its own length, updated as changes to the list are made.

Answer (score 1):

In C `strlen()` is an *O*(*n*) operation because it has to scan for the `\0` terminator. Very few languages use C's representation for strings. Most, including Python, store the length in a separate field so it doesn't have to be computed on demand.

See [PEP 393](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0393/#specification) for an exact specification of how Python stores strings. It's complicated because it switches between representations to save space when strings consist solely of ASCII characters, but the field in question is the first one, `length`.

> ```c
> typedef struct {
>   PyObject_HEAD
>   Py_ssize_t length;                    // <--------------
>   Py_hash_t hash;
>   struct {
>       unsigned int interned:2;
>       unsigned int kind:2;
>       unsigned int compact:1;
>       unsigned int ascii:1;
>       unsigned int ready:1;
>   } state;
>   wchar_t *wstr;
> } PyASCIIObject;
>
> typedef struct {
>   PyASCIIObject _base;
>   Py_ssize_t utf8_length;
>   char *utf8;
>   Py_ssize_t wstr_length;
> } PyCompactUnicodeObject;
>
> typedef struct {
>   PyCompactUnicodeObject _base;
>   union {
>       void *any;
>       Py_UCS1 *latin1;
>       Py_UCS2 *ucs2;
>       Py_UCS4 *ucs4;
>   } data;
> } PyUnicodeObject;
> ```
>
> The fields have the following interpretations:
>
> - **`length`: number of code points in the string (result of `sq_length`)**
> - `interned`: interned-state (SSTATE_*) as in 3.2
> - `kind`: form of string
>
>   - 00 => str is not initialized (data are in wstr)
>   - 01 => 1 byte (Latin-1)
>   - 10 => 2 byte (UCS-2)
>   - 11 => 4 byte (UCS-4);
> - `compact`: the object uses one of the compact representations (implies ready)
> - `ascii`: the object uses the PyASCIIObject representation (implies compact and ready)
> - `ready`: the canonical representation is ready to be accessed through `PyUnicode_DATA` and `PyUnicode_GET_LENGTH`. This is set either if the object is compact, or the `data` pointer and `length` have been initialized.
> - `wstr_length`, `wstr`: representation in platform's `wchar_t` (null-terminated). If `wchar_t` is 16-bit, this form may use surrogate pairs (in which cast `wstr_length` differs form `length`). `wstr_length` differs from length only if there are surrogate pairs in the representation.
> - `utf8_length`, `utf8`: UTF-8 representation (null-terminated).
> - `data`: shortest-form representation of the unicode string. The string is null-terminated (in its respective representation).

Full source code for the [CPython string implementation](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/python/cpython/master/Objects/unicodeobject.c) is on GitHub.