# String concat with single char complexity on Python

Tags: python-3.x, string, time-complexity

a = "abc"

a += 'd'

is adding single char at the end of string still O(n) operation where n is length of 'a'?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61427413/why-isnt-the-string-len-operator-on-in-python

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.